# Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - aws.yml) in rails with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Rais application deployed in aws elastic beantalk. Images are not loading from assets folder. I am trying to use s3 bucket to store assets. I got an error...

aws.yml

```
 production:
  access_key_id: 123333231331....
  secret_access_key: 12212dddddd........
```

production.rb

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :preserve_files => true,
  :s3_credentials => 'aws.yml',
  :s3_region => 'ap-south-1',
  :s3_host_name => 's3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com',
  :bucket => 'xxxxxx'
}
```

I also give public access permissions in s3 bucket.

```
anyone: read write
```

gem...

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.10', '>= 2.10.85'
```

aws.yml folder within config folder -- config/aws.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the path to the file, as at the bottom of your question: `:s3_credentials => 'config/aws.yml'`.

Otherwise, you might need to explicitly load the file from YAML and pass this in:

```
require 'yaml'
...
# again, perhaps using config/aws.yml, have a play
:s3_credentials => YAML.load_file('aws.yml')
...
```

Either of those help?

Comment: very thank you... i got it... :s3_credentials => 'config/aws.yml'